# Display date in header of left my cell below based on specific input

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a formula that currently looks for the left-most cell with a number or number/"c" combination and then displays the date in the header above.

I would like to modify the formula to function with the following values as well:

```
100c/100C, 
12/12c, 
100c101, 
100c100c, 
100C/101C, 
100C   101C (omit spaces),
100c    101 (omit spaces),
101    (Omit spaces)
```

The formula should exclude all cells without numbers, such as CO or MT

Please see link below for reference:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NdnlC-YvaLA_KOZp_xVVsTXsB4ToBqeJPBwhqyzvgXg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: not sure if I fully understand, but maybe something like this [`\d+[cC]?\/?\s*\d*\d+[cC]?`](https://regex101.com/r/EoZCBc/1)

Comment: if you exclude only values without digits, it would be much simpler like just `\d`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with query like this:

```
=query(transpose(H10:AC12),"select Col1 where Col3='100/101c' or Col3='100/10C' or Col3='100c/101C' or Col3='100C/101C' or Col3='100C101C' or Col3='100101C' or Col3='12/12c' limit 1")
```

Format the cell the formula is in as as Mo=Day (08-05).